# Pandas: How to group the non-continuous date column?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column in a dataframe which contains non-continuous dates. I need to group these date by a frequency of 2 days. Data Sample(after normalization):

```
2015-04-18 00:00:00    
2015-04-20 00:00:00    
2015-04-20 00:00:00    
2015-04-21 00:00:00    
2015-04-27 00:00:00    
2015-04-30 00:00:00    
2015-05-07 00:00:00    
2015-05-08 00:00:00
```

I tried following but as the dates are not continuous I am not getting the desired result.

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key = 'l_date', freq='2D'))
```

Is these a way to achieve the desired grouping using pandas or should I write a separate logic?

Comment: " I am not getting the desired result.", what output do you get?

Comment: Your code groups together dates with bins of 2 calendar days. Do you just want to group together consecutive rows?

Comment: @ALollz That is right.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a `l_date` sorted dataframe. you can create a *continuous* ***dummy date*** (`dum_date`) column and groupby `2D` *frequency* on it.

```
df = df.sort_values(by='l_date')
df['dum_date'] = pd.date_range(pd.datetime.today(), periods=df.shape[0]).tolist()

df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key = 'dum_date', freq='2D'))
```

***OR***

If you are fine with groupings other than *dates*. then a *generalized* way to group `n` *consecutive rows* could be:

```
n = 2                                                      # n = 2 for your use case
df = df.sort_values(by='l_date')
df['grouping'] = [(i//n + 1) for i in range(df.shape[0])]

df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key = 'grouping'))
```